# How to change attributes of leaflet-sidebar-v2 based on 'id'?

Tags: javascript

I using [leaflet-sidebar-v2](https://github.com/nickpeihl/leaflet-sidebar-v2) and I'm wondering how can I change the attribute of a tab based on their id:

```
  ctlSidebar = L.control.sidebar({container:'sidebar_div'}).addTo(mymap);

  ctlSidebar.addPanel({
    id:   'info',
    tab:  '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>', // Font Awesome icon
    title: 'info',
    pane: 'some info'
  });


sidebar.on('opening', function() {
    //Change the 'tab' of ID == 'info' to '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>';
})

sidebar.on('closing', function() {
    //Change the 'tab' of ID == 'info' to '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>';
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining the tab button, I'd assign an ID to it.
In the event handlers, change its classes:

```
// note the id
ctlSidebar.addPanel({
  tab:  '<i id="my-dynamic-tab" class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
  ...
})

ctlSidebar.on('opening', function() {
  document.getElementById('my-dynamic-tab').className = 'fa fa-minus'
})

ctlSidebar.on('closing', function() {
  document.getElementById('my-dynamic-tab').className = 'fa fa-plus'
})
```